# Query taking more time to execute if negative number in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle11g

We have a query in our application, which is having the data of Latitude and Longitude of various cities.

when we pass +ve number as the parameter in Where clause it works fine. but the performance degrades if we pass -ve number.

```
select * 
from ADDRESS 
where Longititude BETWEEN 30 AND 42 ;
```

this performs good

but the following performs bad:

```
select * 
from ADDRESS 
where Longititude BETWEEN -74 AND -73;
```

can someone point out if there is any setting/NLS parameter of the database to be set to have this perform better?

The database is Oracle 11.2.0.3

Comment: Check the execution plan

Comment: What is the data type of `Longitude`?  Is there an index on it?  How much of your data is between -74 and -73?

Comment: Do your queries return similar numbers of rows?  If if -74 is 74 West, then that's the longitude of New York City; you might have a disproportionate number of addresses near there, and a bit farther west.

Comment: The cost of the query in the execution plan for +ve parameter and -ve parameter is as follows:
+ve Parameter : Cost=1
-ve Parameter: Cost=103

Comment: Please run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT .....` for the first query, then `SELECT * FROM Table( DBMS_XPLAN.Display )`, then copy a result of the last query, and append it (as a text) to the question. Next, repeat these steps for the second query. Please also run `SELECT count(*) FROM ADDRESS `, `SELECT count(*) FROM ADDRESS where Longititude BETWEEN -74 AND -73;` and  `SELECT count(*) FROM ADDRESS where Longititude BETWEEN 30 AND 42 ;` and append result of these queries to the question.